Angular 17: Standalone components and not a root service
How can I provide a service that is not at the root of the application, and use the same instance between several components and other services? Not using providers in routes and not using ng module.
I've tried Environment injector, but didn't get any result

You will need to add more details, it's hard to see what the issue is.
Did you use
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})

That's the point, I don't want the service to be root

It is impossible to answer this question if you don't provide any useful information. Why you want to do that? How's the project hierarchy? How are you loading those components?

I've created a sample project with routes and service
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wpj76q?file=src%2Fmain.ts
Thus, the same instance of the service should be available for the first and second components, but not available for the third

"Why you want to do that" - I don't want the service to be root, because it won't be used on all pages, but will only be used for the first and second pages, and in another service

then you need to create a module and define the service as a provider for this module

You can create a Singleton pattern to create a class
Imagine a simple service
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  count:number=0;
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){}
  getData()
  {
    return this.httpClient.get('assets/data.json')
  }
}

We can to have a class ServiceFactory
export class ServiceFactory
{
  private static instance:DataService
  public static create(httpClient: HttpClient)
  {
    if (!this.instance)
      this.instance=new DataService(httpClient)

    return this.instance;
  }
}


See that have a property dataService create as new DataService(httpClient) and the component not inject the data service else use serviceFactory.create() and a getter dataService that will be the serviceFactory.dataService

We can use this ServiceFactory to give value to a variable dataService in the way
@Component({
  selector: 'one',
  standalone: true,
  imports:[JsonPipe],
  template: `
  <h1>one</h1>
    <button (click)="dataService.count=dataService.count+1">
         {{dataService.count}}
    </button>
    <button (click)="click()">getHttp</button>
    {{result|json}}
  `,
  
})


export class One {
  serviceFactory!:ServiceFactory
  result:any;
  constructor(httpClient:HttpClient)
  {
    this.serviceFactory=ServiceFactory.create(httpClient)
  }
  get dataService()
  {
    return this.serviceFactory.dataService
  }


export class One {
  dataService!:DataService
  constructor(httpClient:HttpClient)
  {
      this.dataService=ServiceFactory.create(httpClient);
  }

  click(){
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe({
      next:(res:any)=>this.result=res,
      error:()=>console.log("error")
    })
  }
}

Another component that use the same share the "serviceFactory" and the dataService of the serviceFactory.
One component like
@Component({
  selector: 'three',
  standalone: true,
  template: `...`,
  providers:[DataService]
  
})
export class Three {
  result:any;
  constructor(public dataService:DataService){}
}

have his own instance of the service
I know it's a bit work-around, but this is the stackblitz
UPDATE a more Angular way
If we create a function dataServiceProvider
export const dataServiceProvider = (httpClient:HttpClient)=>
        ServiceFactory.create(httpClient);

We can use provider with useFactory, so our componets like:
@Component({
  selector: 'one',
  standalone: true,
  imports:[JsonPipe],
  template: `...`,
  providers:[{provide:DataService,useFactory:dataServiceProvider,
              deps:[HttpClient]}]
  
})
export class One {
  //we inject in constructor 
  constructor(public dataService:DataService){}
}

a new stackblitz

I solved this problem by redesigning the application architecture using nx and decoupling the connections between services: I moved the common methods into a separate regular ts file, in which these methods simply became pure functions. Thanks to everyone for the answers!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that you found most helpful. - From Review
